# TinyMCE Paste Plugin not style attribute getting stripped out

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-5

TLDR Using the PASTE (not powerpaste) plugin from TinyMCE, I want to keep the "style" attribute from the clipboard when pasting; it appears to be in the clipboard; however, TinyMCE appears to be stripping it

---

I have content from a PDF (PDF can be downloaded here: https://www.docdroid.net/BtHGhjb/test-pdf) that, when copied from Preview (MacOS), inside the clipboard, the style attribute on the span wrapping the word `Test` copied, I can verify this by downloading the document linked from docdroid.net, and opening it in preview, selecting all and clicking copy. Then going to http://static.ephox.com/clipboard/clipboardtest.html and pasting, see below for a screenshot:

[image]

You can see that the span has a bunch of styles added including font-family, font-weight and font-size,

When I paste into TinyMCE, with which I have created a sample @ https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-brook-khp1v?file=/src/App.js what's actually getting pasted is the span WITHOUT the style property. I want to retain that style property.

My configuration can be seen @ https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-brook-khp1v?file=/src/App.js otherwise it is:

```
menubar: false,
          valid_classes: "column",
          paste_retain_style_properties: "all",
          spellchecker_language: "en",
          paste_preprocess: (plugin, args) => {
            console.log(args);
          },
          selector: "textarea",
          advlist_bullet_styles: "square",
          valid_elements: "span[style],b"
```

Any help on how I can retain the style property would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**paste_webkit_styles: "font-weight"**

fixes it for me